# If it's possible, is there an option or other way to change a "Sublist Field" column's display type within a transaction form in NetSuite?

Tags: forms, field, netsuite

I need to change two columns in a Sales Order's item line section (bottom of the page) in NetSuite: https://i.ibb.co/27vx9Dr/2019-06-20-10-41-13-Window.png

It feels like the solution ties these two together as they are both perceived as item line fields or "Sublist Fields" (according to NetSuite's customization form page).

1. INVENTORY DETAIL needs to be enabled or set to "normal" so I can be able to specify bins associated from my selected item or be able to interact and fill in this column at the basic level.
2. AMOUNT needs to be set as "inline-text" so that other people handling sales orders cannot disturb it at all and still be able to see the value of this particular column.

I have attempted to search through `Customization > Lists, Records & Fields` and searched the following options: (which I thought were relevant to the fields that I wanted to modify)

- `Item Fields` to no success
- `Transaction Body Fields` to no success
- `Transaction Line Fields` found out that AMOUNT and INVENTORY DETAIL are both padlocked

I also attempted to search through `Customization > Forms` and I have spent a long time looking through my Sales Order custom transaction form (possibly missing out on menus unintentionally) to no success.

I know that inside `Customization > Forms > Entry Forms` there is an Inventory Detail form in there that shows exactly the window I'm expecting, but I haven't figured out how to customise anything in the columns item line for transaction forms yet so I can create a custom column containing a link to INVENTORY DETAIL simulating the typical behavior of the original one while hiding the disabled one.

Near the top of a Sales Order form, I went to `Customise > Customise Form` and found out that I can find both AMOUNT and INVENTORY DETAIL inside the `Sublist Fields` tab.

Unfortunately, it only has SHOW toggles and this does not do what I need for it to do.

It is clear that I am confusing `Sublist Fields` with `Screen Fields` where I expected there would typically be a DISPLAY TYPE column that bears the drop-down selections containing "Normal", "Inline-Text" and "Disabled" options.

In actuality, they have SHOW checkbox toggles for both INVENTORY DETAIL and AMOUNT where the AMOUNT checkbox is greyed out. (This still does not achieve or reflect what I need it to do)

I am unaware of the conditions that needs to be met for AMOUNT to behave as an inline-text. There is probably another condition that needs to be met for the INVENTORY DETAIL column to be made available somehow.

I admit that I missed something crucial, so please kindly mention about it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create a new column by creating a `Transaction Line Field` that contains two separate fields which are applied to Sales Orders.

For the INVENTORY DETAIL, I went to `Customization > Entry Forms` and copied the link for "Standard Inventory Detail Form" and then produced my own HTML code inside the Default Value when creating a new Transaction Line Field.

For AMOUNT, I created a new transaction line field and then set the Default Value as the appropriate value found in https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2018_1/schema/record/billingaccount.html and I used the curly bracket notation {} to fetch the data for the edittable AMOUNT but changed the Access to View-only, which makes this exactly what I needed.

After previewing the changes into an existing Sales Order, I can see my results reflected as expected. Consider this question solved.